# preg_replace part of HTML code

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I have hit an issue when I have used `str_replace` so I have decided to go for `preg_replace` but here I do not get results even close to those which I have got with `str_replace`.

An example code looks like:

```
$find_url = '<h3 class="rcc"><a href="'.$new_url;
$replace = '<h3 class="rcc" style="background-color: #ffff00;"><a href="'.$new_url;
$new_data = preg_replace('/$find_url\b/i', $replace, $data);
```

where `$data` is an output of `file_get_contents`

Any clue why `preg_replace` is not working in that case?

Comment: what's in `$new_url`? If it's an absolute url, then you're doing `preg_replace('/<h3>.....href="http://etc...')` and the `/` in `http://` are TERMINATING your pattern, leading to regex syntax errors. And frankly: don't use regexes to mangle html. use DOM. that's what it's there for.

Comment: Yeah it looks like as I'm getting URLs as absolute. 

Side note - any examples on DOM how to do that replace?

Comment: use preg_quote() if you're inserting arbitrary text into a pattern.

Comment: I have wrapped `$find_url` and `$replace` with `preg_quote()` and got an output but nothing got replaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
$regexlink = '#<h3 class="rcc"><a([^>]*) href="([^"/]*/?[^".]*\.[^"]*)"([^>]*)>#';
$replacelink = '<h3 class="rcc" style="background-color: #ffff00;"><a href="$2"  >';
$result = preg_replace($regexlink, $replacelink, $inputdata);
```

Comment: But `$new_url` is a variable based on which `background-color` is added

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - use double quotes in the `preg_replace()`

```
$new_data = preg_replace("/$find_url\b/i", $replace, $data);
```

Single quotes - the regex is interpreting the dollar sign as end of "pattern".

Comment: My test sample (copying a substring from $find_url including the double quotes) actually worked perfectly with a double quoted pattern but not single quoted pattern.